# flex (lexical analyzer) regular expressions - Reusing definitions

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I have this working definition:

```
IDENTIFIER   [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

I don't want to keep repeating the [a-zA-Z] and [0-9], so I made two new definitions

```
DIGIT    [0-9]
VALID    [a-zA-Z]
```

How can I rewrite the IDENTIFIER rule to use the DIGIT and VALID definitions?

I don't know how to do the "second" match, I'm stuck here:

```
IDENTIFIER {VALID}[{VALID}{DIGIT}]* // This syntax is incorrect
```

Thanks.

Edit: The entire test program that I'm using: http://pastebin.com/f5b64183f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you actually want:

```
IDENTIFIER {VALID}({VALID}|{DIGIT})*
```

`[{VALID}{DIGIT}]` resolves to `[[A-Za-z][0-9]]` which is not a legal construct.

Comment: Excellent. You neatly got to the point, unlike me who took three attempts at it. So I've deleted my rather confusing answer. Sorry for no upvote, but I'm used all my votes up for today :(

Comment: @David Arno:  Feel free to come back tomorrow and bump my answer.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do it, but I can't test it.  Do you have sample data?

```
(?:[a-zA-Z])+(?:[0-9])+
```